# Status Code:404 Not Found in angular rest api call

Tags: php, angularjs, .htaccess, rest, slim

I am Using angular for client side with REST method. I am using SLIM Framework in server side But when I am calling url I am getting 404 Not Found on server but It's working perfectly on my local server.
Folder structure is like this

- app

  - app.js
  - contoller.js
- partils

  - template.html
- api

  - lib
  - v1

    - index.php
    - htaccess

.htaccess code is

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```

My live url is http://www.events.websum.co.in/

Comment: I would start by looking in the error log on the sever.

Comment: I would start with using the htaccess that comes with slim :)

Comment: But it's not working on my hosting server

Comment: But you are not using the .htaccess file which comes with Slim. http://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/web-servers.html